# Erro ao usar o invoke para atualizar um listview

Tags: vb.net

Tenho uma thread que chama um método que faz o "Invoke" no listview, só que esse método só funciona com um parâmetro, eu preciso q ele aceite 3.

o meu método:

```
Private Sub Updatelv(ByVal usuarios As String, ByVal status As String, ByVal datahoraAtual As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim args() As String = {usuarios, status, datahoraAtual}

 ## Cabeçalhos ##Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf Updatelv), args)
        Return
    End If
    Me.lstvDados.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {usuarios, status, datahoraAtual}))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

consegui :) :

```
Private Delegate Sub ListViewAddItem_delegate(ByVal destinataio As String, ByVal status As String, ByVal hora As String)

Private Sub ListViewAddItem(ByVal destinataio As String, ByVal status As String, ByVal hora As String)
    If Me.lstvDados.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New ListViewAddItem_delegate(AddressOf ListViewAddItem)
        Me.lstvDados.BeginInvoke(d, {destinataio, status, hora})
    Else
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(destinataio)
        lvi.SubItems.Add(status)
        lvi.SubItems.Add(hora)
        lstvDados.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {lvi})
        lstvDados.Update()
    End If
End Sub
```